# Word for being able to remain calm when doing cruel things

Tags: word-request

For example, Macbeth became guilt-ridden and started to hallucinate after murdering King Duncan and Banquo. So he lacks the ability to remain calm after committing a crime. Is there a word to describe such an ability?

Thanks!

Comment: composure, sangfroid, heartlessness, ruthlessness, mercilessness, lack of pity, pitilessness. You can also google for "ruthlessness synonyms"

Comment: Before the advent of the discipline of Abnormal Psychology, speakers would say that someone "lacked a conscience", i.e. that they had no "moral sense". Today they would be considered psychopaths.  To cast such ruthlessness as an "ability to remain calm" puts a spin on the situation. Are you looking for a term of approbation for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A word to describe such a characteristic would be an adjective so I would say:

> cold-blooded.

According to [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cold-blooded) it means:

> a. Lacking feeling or emotion: a cold-blooded killer.
>
> b. Executed without feeling or emotion: a cold-blooded crime; a cold-blooded performance of the concerto.

Answer (score 1):

Around 1900AD, the terms psychopath and sociopath started being used for people who were callous and showed a lack of empathy, also described as coldheartedness.

People who behaved that way were often also described as having a “callous unconcern for the feelings of others.”

So being psychopathic or sociopathic would be one way.  Thanks to the influence of crime procedural dramas, it's a word in fairly common parlance, rather than being purely jargon.